# All new purchases from Play Store are failing from my Google Account

Tags: google-play-store, google-pay

How do you fix the problem when you try to make a paid purchase it says "Couldn't complete your transaction. Your Play balance can only be used in Canada. See the fit card terms of service.". I am in Canada.

I've tried purchasing multiple apps from the Play Store on multiple devices. So this error must be associated with my Google Account. My balance is about $50. I use a VPN and have tried with it off but no difference. I have purchased apps in the past and it worked.

Comment: *Your Play balance can only be used in Canada* should be enough as a clue. Are you in Canada or not? Why do you mention VPN?

Comment: @ChanganAuto wouldn't be much of a question if I wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each google account you use is locked to a country.  This is in the Payments section.  You are able to change this once a year only.

For many situations, a VPN is not enough, you need an account in that country.

The solution is to create another google account and change its country to match your target.  Before using it in this country, you need to switch your active account in PlayStore.  This works in a few more situations, but still has limitations.

**Changing Account in Playstore**

- Open PlayStore
- Press on your photo
- On the right hand side of your name and account is a drop-down arrow
- Use it to change your account.

**Changing Country on your Account**

- On a browser go to play.google.com/store/games
- Click on your photo/icon
- Click on `Payments and Subscriptions`

If you dont have a method allocated then

- Click on `Add a payment method`
- Enter credit card details (you wont be charged)
- Enter Billing address in the new country.

If you already have a method allocated

- Click on `Edit payment methods`
- Choose a card and click on `Edit`
- Edit your billing address (to the new country).

Comment: All of this appears to be correct. My credit cards are here as well as the Google Play Balance. Is there something in particular I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

**Setting your DNS servers to default may do the trick.**

Had the same problem driving me up the wall. Solution for my Android device was:
Settings -> Connections -> More Connection settings -> Private DNS
Mine was set to "Automatic (recommended)"
I changed it to "Off" and was able to make payments in Google again...

Not sure why the DNS server would have an effect on the detected device location, but I recommend also checking DNS settings in the Router and other network settings (e.g. VPN etc.) to see if that fixes your problem.